# Understanding Unix Timestamps and Time Zone Conversion in Python

Tags: datetime, timestamp, unix-timestamp, python-datetime, timezone-offset

I'm having trouble understanding Unix timestamps and time zone conversions in Python. I have a UTC datetime string ('2023-09-20T05:04:54') and latitude/longitude coordinates (around Toronto). I need to convert this UTC time to local time and obtain Unix timestamps for both, expecting a 4-hour time difference between UTC and Toronto time. However, both timestamps appear the same.

```
# The input time and lat/lon
utc = '2023-09-20T05:04:54'
latitude = 43.477361 
longitude = -80.513589

# Find the time zone according to lat/lon
tf = TimezoneFinder()
local_timezone = tf.timezone_at(lng=longitude, lat=latitude)
local_timezone = ZoneInfo(local_timezone)  # Convert string to timezone object

# Make sure the input time (utc) is recognized as UTC time by Python
utc_time = datetime.strptime(utc, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)

# Convert to local time ('America/Toronto')
local_time = utc_time.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).astimezone(local_timezone)

# Print Unix timestamps
local_time.timestamp()
#Out[158]: 1695186294.0
utc_time.timestamp()
#Out[159]: 1695186294.0
```

The time offset between UTC and the Toronto time zone should be -4 hours. However, the Unix timestamps for UTC and Toronto time are the same. Can someone explain why there is no 4-hour difference in the timestamps?

Comment: Unix timestamps are UTC, by definition.

Comment: Yes, what @tkausl said.  Python is converting the time to UTC before it calculates the timestamp.

Comment: OK, I understood, it is the length of time instead of the actual date time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `datetime.timestamp()` method returns a unix timestamp. A unix timestamp is number of seconds since Jan 1, 1970 **UTC**. Hence, regardless of the time zone, it will always return the same time, since they're both the same number of seconds from the 'epoch time' of Jan 1, 1970 **UTC**

You can always calculate the time offset from 2 timezones using the [pytz library](https://pypi.org/project/pytz/):

```py
from pytz import timezone
import pandas as pd

def tz_diff(date, tz1, tz2):
    '''
    Returns the difference in hours between timezone1 and timezone2
    for a given date.
    '''
    date = pd.to_datetime(date)
    return (tz1.localize(date) - 
            tz2.localize(date).astimezone(tz1))\
            .seconds/3600
```

Comment: OK, I understood, it is the length of time instead of the actual date time.

Comment: Why are you using pytz **and** pandas? That feels like wrapping a sausage in a steak to make another sausage ;-) [dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) for instance would give you a generic parser *and* timezone handling. But why even bother with parsing and tz handling, why not make that the responsibility of the caller and only accept two aware datetime objects?

Comment: btw. `.astimezone(tz1)` is not needed since timedelta arithmetic is wall time arithmetic.

Comment: This is my first experience with Python, and I appreciate your recommendation to explore the dateutil package. I'm currently working with meteorological station data from various global locations, which are stored as CSV files. I chose pandas to handle this data format. My goal is to synchronize this meteorological station data with other datasets based on timestamps, which is why I incorporated pytz. Thank you for providing a more efficient solution!@FObersteiner

Comment: @QinghuanLi if you're working with pandas anyway, it has all the functionality you need for datetime and time zone handling build-in. You can do everything with pandas methods; most of the time there is no need for vanilla Python datetime, pytz, dateutil etc.